# Replace 1 line in text file Linq c#

Tags: c#, linq, text, replace

I have text file with contain:

ABCD

QWERT

8:20 AM

78910

in the line 3 I want replace to:8:20 AM -> 9:25 AM

try code:

```
string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
file = file.Select((x, i) => i > 1 && i < 3 ? x.Replace("8:20 AM", "9:25 AM") : x).ToArray();
File.WriteAllLines(filename, file);
```

resultz:

ABCD

QWERT

8:20 AM 9:25 AM

78910

can help me replace all text in line 3 of text file. Thanks

Comment: Why are you using replace if you simply want to change the entire line? Just return "9:25 AM".

Comment: because i don't find other solution. i only want change time in line 3. If you know it please help me fix it

Comment: `? "9:25 AM" : x`

Comment: ```File.WriteAllText(filename,File.ReadAllText(filename).Replace("8:20 AM", "8:20 AM 9:25 AM"))```

Comment: however, the times in line 3 are always changing. Is there any way to change "8: 20 Am"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two issues with your code:

1. You're using `Replace`, which looks in the string `x` for `"8:20 AM"` and replaces that value with `"9:25 AM"` returning a new string value. You always want the same value to be written to the file, regardless of what's currently on that line in the file. You should therefore return a string literal (`"9:25 AM"`) rather than the result of a replace on `x`.
2. Your condition: `i > 1 && i < 3`. `i` is an `int` (integer) meaning that it only holds *whole* values. Why don't you simply check `i == 2` instead?

```cs
string[] file = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
file = file.Select((x, i) => i == 2 ? "9:25 AM" : x).ToArray();
File.WriteAllLines(filename, file);
```

Comment: Yeap, this is what I want. thanks for your support!

Answer (score -2):

why using array, you can use list instead it will be much more easier for you.

```
 string[] file =  File.ReadAllLines(filename);
 var newList = string.Join(" ", file).Split('\n').Select(s => s.Replace("8:20 AM", "9:25 AM")).ToList();

            string output="";
            foreach(var item in newList)
            {
                output += item + "\n";
            }

File.WriteAllLines(filename, output);
```

Try this. This works, However you have to make sure that the string your getting from textfile is always separated by newline or "\n";

Comment: however, the times in line 3 are always changing.  Is there any way to change "8: 20 Am"?

Comment: @Kevil This is a generally wrong answer, so please ignore it.

Comment: John, I'll calrify the problems with your code here. 1. `File.ReadAllLines(filename)` will read each line of the file as an array, meaning that none of the entires should contain any `\n` or `\rn` characters. 2. You're making the entire file into one long line, which each original line of the file being separated by a space character. 3. Splitting this long line by `\n` will give you an array of string with a single item, because there are no `\n` characters. 4. You're then converting that single item to a single-item list.

Comment: 5. You're building string output from that single item, which will effectively be the entire original contents of the file on a single line separated by spaces, with the time replaced, terminated with a single `\n` character. 6. You're using `WriteAllLines` and passing a single string, rather an array of string or `IEnumerable<string>`, meaning that this line will produce a compiler error as `WriteAllLines` doesn't have a `params string[]` signature. 7. Your code assumes that newline is `\n` (line feed) but on Windows, a newline is comprised of `\r` (carriage return) AND `\n` (line feed): \r\n

Comment: I fixed your `File.WriteAllLines` to `File.WriteAllText` so that it would compile, and I created a [before and after](https://imgur.com/a/UEuHRhu) of the file, which I ran through your code.

Comment: Thanks for your support, i found solution from @John